# about java scanner. Error: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

Tags: java

I'm a oversea student. I use blueJ do my assessment. My code could run in terminal well, but after I submit my assessment the page response fails and shows

> java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found

My code:

```
public void input() {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Move (l/r/u/d): ");
    String name = keyboard.nextLine();

    if(name.equals("l")) {
        move(-1,0);
    }
    else if(name.equals("r")) {
        move(1,0);
    }
    else if(name.equals("u")) {
        move(0,-1);
    }
    else if(name.equals("d")) {
        move(0,1);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Invalid move");
    }
}
```

Comment: My only guess is that your testing server doesn't have the `util` package, which I don't think is even possible!

Comment: Have you tried checking API for a deeper diagnosis? [link] (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you read the requirements for your assignments again carefully.

The symptoms clearly indicate that your program is being tested in a context in which there is no input to be read from `System.in`.  The most obvious explanation is that your program is supposed to be getting its input some other way.  But unless we see the requirements, we cab only guess what it is supposed to do.

I guess another possibility is that the program that is testing your assignment code is faulty.

Answer (score -2):

By seeing the error line not found,u replace `print()` into `println()`.